# Force horizontal scrollbar to frontpage

Tags: css, wordpress, scrollbar

My question is how I via. the CSS can force my webpage to show a horizontal scroolbar on the frontpage.

I've triede looking for overflow-x: but can't seem to find the right place.

My webpage: http://holtumdata.dk

I've had customers who have trouble finding the "Download" page, when they're on computers with small screens. (open browser in window mode, to see what I mean.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'overflow-x:scroll' for 'body' doesn't work?

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here looking at your page I can see that you have a HTML line like this

```
<div id="portfolio_viewport" style=" overflow: hidden;  outline: none; cursor: -webkit-grab;" tabindex="5000">
```

Remove the overflow:hidden in element's style

but since CSS is generated from module we can override it locally by using script like

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

#portfolio_container {
overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Wandel There is another `overflow:hidden` in a div below.Please also remove that. `<div id="portfolio_container" class="ql_height isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 3672px; height: 290px;">`

Comment: Tried searching for portfolio_container but I can't seem to find it with a overflow: hidden;

Comment: Are you generating the css somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about generating. I'm just editing the stylesheet.

Comment: The div is in your html/php file. Just hit ctrl + f and search for portfolio_container in whatever program you are using. It's there. It's in the portfolio_viewport div.

Comment: I'm able to find the portfolio_container, but can't see any overflow: hidden; in them.

Comment: That's what I meant with generating css, are you using javascript or anything to add overflow:hidden; to the portfolio_container div?

Comment: I haven't coded the page myself, I'm just editing a wordpress theme, so I haven't set up a javascript.

Comment: Sorrry but I can't look at the theme code. Well I can, but it is minimized and takes a while to look through..

Comment: add this CSS to your page  `<style media="screen" type="text/css">

#portfolio_container {
overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

</style>`

Answer (score 0):

You put it in the html{} in your css file.

And a mozilla firefox specific one: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal

Like this:

```
html{
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: adding overflow-x:scroll in html isn't changing anything.

Comment: Look at the comment above me, try to remove the overflow: hidden; in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I check your site.. By applying `overflow-x:scroll`
your problem may be solved .

In CSS :

```
body{

    overflow-x:scroll;

   }
```